# ASP.net control Postback Problem (Can't read the value the user entered!)

Tags: asp.net, events, custom-controls, web-controls

I've written a custom widget to allow a user to select a location from a database of locations.  This is my first ASP.net custom control.  It seemed like everything was working fine, but now there's a problem.

My control implements the RaisePostBackEvent function as follows:

```
public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
{
    SelectedLocationId = eventArgument.Split('|')[0];
    SelectedLocationDescription = eventArgument.Split('|')[1];
}
```

I wrote a test page and included the following in my ASP code:

```
<%= locationSelector.SelectedLocationId %>
```

That worked fine.

However, in my web application, the following code does *not* work:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
         Response.Write(locationSelector.SelectedLocationId);
         // SelectedLocationId is null here!!!
    }
```

When I run this code in the debugger, I see that my Page Load event fires *before* the Post Back event!  Therefore, the data is not yet read from the postback.  I know that using the MS provided text field control, the text is available at Page Load, so I think I must be doing something wrong.

How can I read the location that the user selected when the Page Load event fires?  To clarify, I'm refering to the Page Load of a web application page.

Answer (score 3):

You're setting SelectedLocationId on a postback event and at the same time you are trying to retrieve its value on the first load. SelectedLocationId will be null all right.

Try:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (locationSelector != null)
         Response.Write(locationSelector.SelectedLocationId);
    }
```

Comment: My apologies, the code I posted is not the real code, and it should have been `if Page.IsPostBack`, not `if !Page.IsPostBack`. In anycase, I can read the value the user entered using a code block on the page, but not on the Page Load event.